# How to use added table in tablecell asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I added the table in TableCell

```
Dim rSkala As New TableRow()
Dim cSkala As New TableCell()
cSkala.Controls.Add(New Table())
rSkala.Cells.Add(cSkala)
```

How can I use this table now? I want add to the table rows and cells, but this table haven't name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must assign programmatically the ID of the control:

```
Dim rSkala As New TableRow()
Dim cSkala As New TableCell()
Dim newTable as New Table()
newTable.ID = "myID"
cSkala.Controls.Add(newTable)
rSkala.Cells.Add(cSkala)
```

At this point your table has an ID to be referenced (es. with `FindControl("myID`"))